# How to show the doughtnut chart label as td wise?

Tags: chart.js, laravel-6

[image]

I am working on a doughnut chart using chart.js and I face alignment issues on labels, I can't use the CSS to fix it.

My code:

```
options:{
  legend : {
      position: 'bottom',
      align:"start",
      fullwidth:600,
            labels: {
            usePointStyle: true,
            boxWidth: 6,
            fontSize:9,
            fontFamily: "sans-serif"
          },
        },
}
  layout: {
        padding:{
            top:10,
            left:80,
            right:30,
            bottom: 0,
            paddingleft:10
        }
      }
```

Comment: this might help https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels

Comment: Thanks for your response Palak Jadav